# get selected value from dropdown in angularjs and use it in input field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hello I am new to angularjs and making a unit convertor demo app,I have two dropdown for units(destination and source unit).I want to get selected values to an input text and want to do some calculcation on that.can anyone please help me to do so,My code is as below:

**html**

```
 <body ng-app="starter" class="platform-android platform-cordova platform-webview">

    <ion-pane>
      <!--<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">-->
        <!--<h1 class="title">Ionic - Teste DataBase</h1>-->
      <!--</ion-header-bar>-->
      <ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
          <button class="button" ng-click="insert('Brian', 'Mendes')">Insert</button>
          <button class="button" ng-click="con()">Select</button>

        <button class="button" ng-click="show()">show</button>




<table>
<div>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ sourceunit }}</td><p>
        <td>
            <p>
        <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
           Source Unit:
        <select
                ng-model="address.state"
                ng-options="state.lookupCode as state.description for state in lov_state"></select>
        <tt>State selected: {{address.state}}</tt>
        {{option.show1}}
        </div>
        </p></td>
        </p>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>
         <p><input type="number" style="background-color:lightgrey;" ng-click="sourcevalue" ng-model="value"></input></p>


        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Destination_Unit</td>
        <td>
            <p>  <div ng-repeat="dest in dests">
            Source Unit:
            <select
                    ng-model="dest.state"
                    ng-options="state.lookupCode as state.description for state in lov_dest"></select>
            <tt>State selected: {{dest.state}}</tt>
            {{option.show1}}
        </div></p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> Convert_Value</td>
        <td>   <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Converted value"
                      ng-model="dest.state" class="input-width" ng-init ="dest.state"/>
    </tr>

    <td>
        <p>

        </p></td>
    <select ng-click="temp()" ng-options="option for option in listOfOptions"
            ng-model="selectedItem">
    </select>


</div>
</table>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

**js**

```
var db = null;
 var live=[];
 var src=[];
 var gUnit = '';
var example = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

example.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }

        if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }


db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "Converter.sqlite"});
console.log("database path:: " , db);

  });
})

example.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {

 var vm = this;

  vm.unitList = [];
  gUnit ='';
  //temp jigar
   $scope.addresses = [{'state': 'Select Unit'} ];
   $scope.dests  = [{'state': 'Select Unit'} ];

      $scope.lov_state = [ {'lookupCode': 'Select Unit', 'description': 'Select Unit'}];
       $scope.lov_dest = [ {'lookupCode': 'Select Unit', 'description': 'Select Unit'}];

 $scope.show = function() {
//    alert("show function");
        var results=[];
        //alert("======MY SELECTED UNIT VALUE IS------>"+$scope.show1);
         var query = "SELECT unit,formula FROM Length;";
         $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
             if(res.rows.length > 0) {
              for (var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++) {
                var unitname = res.rows.item(i).unit;
                 var unitvalue = res.rows.item(i).formula;
                   vm.unitList.push({name: unitname, value: unitvalue});
                    results.push( res.rows.item(i).formula);

                      $scope.lov_state.push({lookupCode: unitvalue, description: unitname});
                      $scope.lov_dest.push({lookupCode: unitvalue, description: unitname});
//
                          }
                            $scope.addresses  = results;
                           if (vm.unitList.length === 0) {
                                                  $scope.unit = false;
                                              } else {
                                                  $scope.unit = true;
                                              }
                                              vm.selectedUnit = gUnit;
                                               } else {
                                                      console.log("No results found");
                                                    }
         }, function (err) {
             console.error(err);
         });

         $scope.convertvalue = "6";
     }




$scope.sourceunit="Sourceunit";


$scope.show1= function(){

          var query = "SELECT unit FROM Length;";
          var results=[];
          $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
if(res.rows.length > 0) {

             for (var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++) {

                    results.push( res.rows.item(i).unit);
                        $scope.list =results;
             }
             }
 else {

                  console.log("No results found");
              }
          }, function (err) {
              console.error(err);
          });
}
```

Comment: Selected value will be stored in `$scope.address.state`. Access and perform calculation and set result to `$scope.calculatedValue` and use this variable as model for input

Comment: Could you please post only the html and js parts that are required for the understanding of the problem ?

Comment: @rajesh can you pls help me in my existing one.i cant understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$scope.$watch` to check if value is changed. This will triggered as soon as a value is changed.

#### Syntax

```
$scope.$watch('variableName', function(newValue, oldValue){
  // do your logic here.
});
```

You can refer following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qpo00wc/1/) for reference. This is a very basic implementation and should be considered as reference.

Comment: Thats what i am looking for but its not working with my code,..can you help me for my one?

Comment: @sulphuricAcid I have created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/sq83mopq/) of your code, but some injector error is coming. Can you resolve them?

Comment: @Rajesh-I have tried but no luck..can i send you the code?

Comment: @sulphuricAcid You can edit fiddle that I have shared and once it is in working state, post link in your question and everyone can help you.

Comment: rajesh - Plesae see my fiddel here...can you help me for it? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/td2nz/)...Please hope you can help me.i want to multiply both values. and want to display it.

Comment: @sulphuricAcid Find the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/Td2NZ/1488/)

Comment: @rajesh-Please see your updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/Td2NZ/1488/) ...i want to multiply both the values and display it in a textlabel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105224/discussion-between-rajesh-and-sulphuric-acid).